# gstreamer's decodebin for RTP and RTSP

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I have two different IP cameras (orlaco and axis).

I can see the image from the axis camera (streaming RTSP) with next gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://root:axis@192.168.82.51:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=jpeg" latency=1000 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! waylandsink
```

With orlaco camera (streaming RTP), I can see the image with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! waylandsink
```

but if I try this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! waylandsink
```

I get this:

```
Missing element: application/x-rtp decoder
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
../../../gst-plugins-base-1.16.1/gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c(4678): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: application/x-rtp (application/x-rtp, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26)
```

So, is there a way to somehow reduce the pipeline for the 2nd camera?